# Twitter Cursors

Tags: twitter

Do the page 'cursors' on the Twitter Api change. What I mean by this is if the cursor ID for the second page of results was 123456789 will it still be the same every time or does it change.

For example if

> http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json&screen_name=XXXXXXX&cursor=123456789

returns followers X, Y, Z for user XXXXXXX, will it always return X, Y, Z (assuming X, Y, Z are still following that user)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cursors essentially do not change.

> A cursor is an opaque
>   deletion-tolerant index into a Btree
>   keyed by source userid and
>   modification time. It brings you to a
>   point in time in the reverse chron
>   sorted list. So, since you can't
>   change the past, other than erasing
>   it, it's effectively stable.
>   (Modifications bubble to the top.) But
>   you have to deal with additions at the
>   list head and also block shrinkage due
>   to deletions, so your blocks begin to
>   overlap quite a bit as the data ages.
>   (If you cache cursors and read much
>   later, you'll see the first few rows
>   of cursor[n+1]'s block as duplicates
>   of the last rows of cursor[n]'s block.
>   The intersection cardinality is equal
>   to the number of deletions in
>   cursor[n]'s block). Still, there may
>   be value in caching these cursors and
>   then heuristically rebalancing them
>   when the overlap proportion crosses
>   some threshold.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/twitter-development-talk/cStHZQKNUnw/1ucp0gfwWvAJ